# Cmake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Write to restore size failed

Tags: cmake

I'm getting this error when running `cmake ..`;

```
... {more warnings, all unkown}
cmake -E tar: warning: unknown warning
cmake -E tar: warning: unknown warning
cmake -E tar: warning: unknown warning
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Write to restore size failed
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: /mnt/c/inav/downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2
CMake Error at cmake/arm-none-eabi-checks.cmake:84 (message):
  error extracting gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/arm-none-eabi-checks.cmake:107 (arm_none_eabi_gcc_install)
  cmake/arm-none-eabi-checks.cmake:119 (arm_none_eabi_gcc_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Completely new to anything command line related, and have gotten this error following a step-by-step instruction on multiple computers. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Linux subsystem on Windows. I have seen similar problems posted on stack exchange, but never this exact error, so I'm wondering if I did something really stupid that is preventing me from running CMake.

Please don't with-hold any suggestions because they seem too obvious- I am completely new to this and haven't tried any troubleshooting. OR if you know where to unzip this file, could I just do it manually?

Comment: The most obvious question would be why are you trying to build cmake, rather than simply installing pre-compiled package from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: I was following a tutorial and this was the method they used. I didn't know there was another way.

Comment: Yeah unless you need a specific *version* of a program then installing from the repository (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install cmake`) is always the surest way.

Comment: So to replace "cmake (path)" would I just install cmake to that same path? Sorry if what I'm saying makes no sense, I am a complete noob and just going through all this trouble to recompile other code with one word changed.

Comment: Can you give us some context? With apt, you don't really get to choose the installation path. My guess is that `cmake (path)` just means to *run* cmake with the path to a specific CMakeLists.txt file - typically `cmake .` (file is in the current directory) or `cmake ..` (file is in the parent directory)

Comment: Yeah sorry I dont really have any context, I am following a tutorial with 0 experience. The command that triggered this is "CMake . ."

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, I just tried again and it worked. don't know what changed